# JavaScript refresh file contents

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having D3 JS load the contents of a file (which has CSV values). However the values in the file will change. Without refreshing the whole browser window, how can I get it to pull in the new data?

This is my code at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<body>

<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("test2.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

});

</script>

</body>
```

I think I might need to call `data.forEach(function(d)` again? But I've tried this:

```
<script>
var int=self.setInterval(data.forEach(function(d), 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: looks like when setting interval you use function(d) without any body, so nothing is executed.

Comment: @AlexYokisama Thank you for the help. I'm not sure what you mean I am afraid :(

Comment: Hi Jimmy. You don't need to use triple backticks here - they do not do anything. In some versions of Markdown they are used for block code formatting, but that is not supported on Stack Exchange sites. Please stick to single backticks, so your questions are easier to edit in the future.

Comment: We also prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.csv()` will pass file contents to it's callback at the time it is execution. It doesn't matter how many times you loop over the data inside the callback, it will be the same data that you are looping over.

To load the data again, you should call `d3.csv()` again which will call the callback with the new data.

See my example below (untested) when I have extracted the callback to a named function, and called `d3.csv` every minute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<body>

<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Created a reusable function for the callback
function handleCsvData(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.value = +d.value;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

}

// Call d3.csv every minute and pass contents to callback
var csvReloadInterval = setInterval(d3.csv("test2.csv", handleCsvData), 60000);
// Call d3.csv for the first time
d3.csv("test2.csv", handleCsvData);

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: you must clear the svg first at the start of the drawing

Answer (score 1):

You have to call d3.csv() again to check for updates.
See here for an extended example:
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6bd13f974d6516f3e491